# I just upgraded to 13.10 in my virtual machine through Virtual Box but can restart successfully

Tags: upgrade, 13.10, virtualbox, restart, virtualization

This is what i see after i restart.

[image: http://www.flickr.com/photos/93691468@N03/10762341305/in/photostream/]

How can i fix this?  Am i suppose to type in a command?  Is restoring my host computer to a later point a possible option?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you may have a hardware conflict for it to boot to in that fashion. Instead of upgrading the image inside of the virtual machine, you can simply download a new image of the upgraded OS and boot the VM from that image. For any files that you need cross platform, use dropbox or Google drive!